# How to use parameters in a SQL Task in SSIS?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, ssis, sql-server-2012

I'm working on a datawarehouse.

I wrote a script to loada dimention table by creating date entries (such as the SSAS wizard but directly in my SSIS ETL process). It works well in SSMS and directly in a T-SQL task in SSIS without using parameters).
This script doesn't provide any ResultSet, this is just a loop to insert data in a table.

Here is a quick look of my query.

```
USE [MySQLServerDatabase]
GO

-- Some parameters used by the script.
DECLARE @PREFIX_YEAR_NAME       [nvarchar](50) = 'Year ';
DECLARE @PREFIX_QUARTER_NAME    [nvarchar](50) = 'Q';
DECLARE @PREFIX_WEEK_NAME       [nvarchar](50) = 'W';
DECLARE @PREFIX_MONTH_NAME      [nvarchar](50) = 'M';
DECLARE @DefaultBeginDate       [datetime]  = '01/01/2000';
DECLARE @Date                   [datetime];

SET @Date = @BeginDate

WHILE @Date <= @EndDate
    BEGIN
        -- ...
        -- INSERT INTO ...
    END

-- ...
```

However, to get something more easy to use and to maintain, I would like to use SSIS variables directly in the script.

Here is my params (Project.params file).
My script needs all of them to work :

[image]

Then, I added a "Execute SQL Task component" containing my SQL query (OLEDB connection, direct input method). I created my 5 parameters :

[image]

How to use parameters in the SQL query ?
I tried to use the same name as the variables in the script, it doesn't work.
I tried to use indexes (0,1,2 etc.) names and to use '?' in the script, I doesn't work.

Here is the error when using '?' as parameters :

> Error: 0xC002F210 at Execute SQL Task, Execute SQL Task: Executing the
>   query " DECLARE  @PREFIX_YEAR_NAME  nvarchar = ?; D..." failed
>   with the following error: "Multiple-step OLE DB operation generated
>   errors. Check each OLE DB status value, if available. No work was
>   done.". Possible failure reasons: Problems with the query, "ResultSet"
>   property not set correctly, parameters not set correctly, or
>   connection not established correctly. Task failed: Execute SQL Task

Any idea to solve that ?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you post the sql script you used with the ? as parameters?

Answer (score 0):

you can put this query into stored procedure. In SQL Task Editor in SQLStatement you can execute it by exec [sch].[sp_name] ?,?,?...,? (each ? is one parameter).
In your 'Parameter Mapping' tab in Parameter Name column you can use numbers 0, 1, 2... n (it's order of params in your stored procedure).

Comment: Is creating a stored procedure the only way to use that ? Because I did the same thing without using a store procedure and it failed.

Comment: @K4timini No, this is not limited to procs.  It works with ad hoc sql statements as well.  What is the error?

Comment: In your SQL Task Editor you have an option 'Result Set'. Is it set to 'None'?

Comment: The thing is the error message isn't helpful because you're using multi-step sql.  If you put it in a stored proc, you might get a more useful error message.   @MarkWojciechowicz, see the error message in the OP.

Comment: @TabAlleman sorry - I was being hopeful K4timini had another go at it after the answer was posted and there was a new problem.  I just noticed the original image is using [at sign]parmName for the parameter names.  K4timini Have you indeed converted these to 0,1,2... this is the correct convention for an OLEDB connection.